# Android league app keeps crashing

Tags: java, android, android-intent, counter

Need a bit of help, creating an app that sends the results of ten team name, games won and drawn does a calculation to work out total points then is supposed to display them
but after the continue button is clicked the app always crashes.
heres the code any guides on whats went wrong
many thanks

```
package com.example.leaguetest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class Display extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);

    //get the the BUNDLE inside the intent
    Bundle m = this.getIntent().getExtras();

    String [] TeamName = m.getStringArray("TeamName");
    String[] SWin = m.getStringArray("Win");
    String[] SDraw =  m.getStringArray("Draw");
    int [] Win = new int[10];
    int [] Draw = new int [10];


    // Convert to from string to integer Win
    Win[1] = Integer.parseInt(SWin[1]);
    Win[2] = Integer.parseInt(SWin[2]);
    Win[3] = Integer.parseInt(SWin[3]);
    Win[4] = Integer.parseInt(SWin[4]);
    Win[5] = Integer.parseInt(SWin[5]);
    Win[6] = Integer.parseInt(SWin[6]);
    Win[7] = Integer.parseInt(SWin[7]);
    Win[9] = Integer.parseInt(SWin[8]);
    Win[9] = Integer.parseInt(SWin[9]);
    Win[10] = Integer.parseInt(SWin[10]);
    // Convert to from string to integer Draw
    Draw[1] = Integer.parseInt(SDraw[1]);
    Draw[2] = Integer.parseInt(SDraw[2]);
    Draw[3] = Integer.parseInt(SDraw[3]);
    Draw[4] = Integer.parseInt(SDraw[4]);
    Draw[5] = Integer.parseInt(SDraw[5]);
    Draw[6] = Integer.parseInt(SDraw[6]);
    Draw[7] = Integer.parseInt(SDraw[7]);
    Draw[8] = Integer.parseInt(SDraw[8]);
    Draw[9] = Integer.parseInt(SDraw[9]);
    Draw[10] = Integer.parseInt(SDraw[10]);


    //Calculation

    int Result1 = (Win[1]* 3)+Draw[1];



    TextView Result1T=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
    Result1T.setText(TeamName[1] );         

    TextView Result2T=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView2);
    Result2T.setText( Result1);










}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.display, menu);
    return true;
}




}
```

---

```
package com.example.leaguetest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


 //global Variables
String [] TeamName = new String[9];
String [] Win = new String[9];
String [] Draw = new String [9];
int counter = 0;

public void Save(View view) {

    EditText Team =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTeamName);
    EditText WinG=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editWin);
    EditText DrawG=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editDraw);
    EditText LossG=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editLoss);


    //If teams not greater than 10 then
    if(counter < 9){

        //putting inputs into array
        TeamName[counter] = Team.getText().toString();
        Win[counter]= WinG.getText().toString();
        Draw[counter]= DrawG.getText().toString();



        counter ++;
    }

    //reset text boxes

        Team.setText("");
        WinG.setText("");
        DrawG.setText("");
        LossG.setText("");
    }//end if



public void Continue(View view) {

    //bundle
    Bundle myBundle =  new Bundle();
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, Display.class);

    //put arrays into the bundle
    myBundle.putStringArray("Name", TeamName);
    myBundle.putStringArray("Win", Win);
    myBundle.putStringArray("Draw", Draw);

    //put the bundle into your intent
    myIntent.putExtras(myBundle);

    //start the activity as defined in the intent
    startActivity(myIntent);

}//end saveNameGrade
```

}

Comment: What error do you get?  Please edit your question to include any error message you get.  "The app crashes" is not enough information for people to diagnose your question without making educated guesses as @selbie has attempted to do.  If the app does simply crash have you made any attempt to debug it yourself?  Including more detail on what you've tried will improve your questions and help you get better answers to future questions

Answer (score 1):

Java array indices are zero based.

This line of code:

```
int [] Win = new int[10];
```

Delcares an array of 10 items.  These items have an index range from 0..9.

This line of code:

```
Win[10] = Integer.parseInt(SWin[10]);
```

Attempts to assign a value out of range for the array.  I also suspect that accessing SWin[10] crashes before that.

I think what you want to say is this:

```
for (int index = 0; index < (SWin.length) && (index < 10); index++)
{
   Win[index] = Integer.ParseInt(SWin[index]);   
}
```

Comment: Tried it and the project still crashes once continue is pressed

Comment: I'm not going to debug your program for you. I suspect you have multiple bugs in your code path above.  I hope to see you make an effort at learning the fundamentals of programming, debugging, settings breakpoints, analyzing exceptions (and logs), and the language/tools you are using.